# _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, python-3.6

i'm using python 3.6 on linux, and i was using matplotlib version 1.5.1, 
so i updated it to latest version 2.2.2

Then there was a problem with a simple code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

when i run this code, error occurred with this message. (the picture popped in a second then it disappeared quickly)

> self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)   File
>   "/home/taegyu/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1782, in wm_attributes
>       return self.tk.call(args)
>   _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window"

After reinstalling with matplotlib version 1.5, I do not see any problem. I think it's probably a problem with tkinter and matplotlib crashes. But i don't know exactly problem and what should i do for this.
Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different [backend](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend), for instance GTK:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Novel. I used Qt4Agg, and i solved this problem.

Comment: @TaegyuNoh then you could mark this as the solution. Also +1 because it helped me as well